# nouveau driver issue when trying to boot ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, dual-boot, graphics, troubleshooting, nouveau

i just installed ubuntu, and it says nouveau failed to idle channel 1 and 2. it also says nouveau playlist update failed. i believe this is a video card driver problem. what can i to to resolve this?

other info

intel i5 2500k 
evga nvidia geforce gtx 560 se
dual booting with windows 7 professional
used wubi to install

i took a photo of the command line text which i can upload if needed

Comment: Try latest 3.6-rc4 kernel, should be fixed there.

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved. Needed to add `nomodeset` to the boot parameters.

Here's a link to a thread with solution: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Answer (score 0):

I had this error while testing 12.10 alpha 3 and had to place 'xforcevesa' in the boot command line to get a screen, but once installed it seemed to clear itself.

Comment: thanks for the reply. im a ubuntu noob, im not sure exactly how to do that. when these errors are being displayed, its a running process, where i cant enter anything. is there some key i should hold/press when i try to boot?

Comment: Please tell the OP exactly how you did this, otherwise this answer is useless.