# Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS x64 live CD or live USB doesn't boot on Gigabyte GA-H97M-HD3 motherboard

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, live-usb, live-cd, motherboard

This is my PC:

- G.Skill Ares DDR3 1600 PC3-12800 8GB 2x4GB CL9
- Gigabyte GA-H97M-HD3
- Intel Core i7-4790 3.6Ghz Box
- Kingston SSDNow V300 120GB
- MSI GeForce GTX750 OC 2GB GDDR5
- Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 1TB SATA3

I have problems booting Ubuntu 14.04.2 live Cd or live USB from fresh (no Windows installed) or other SO. I want to do dual boot with W7.

I configure the motherboard like:

- Boot option 1: DVD
- boot option 2: Lexar USB
- Fast boot: disabled
- Windows 8 Features: Other OS
- Boot mode selection: Legacy Only
- Lan PXE Boot Option ROM: Disabled
- Storage boot option control: Legacy Only
- Other PCI Device ROM priority: Legacy Only
- Network stack: Disabled
- System Mode state: Setup
- Secure Boot state: Disabled

I have no clue what is happening. I tried different DVDs burning in windows and in linux with different Ubuntu images from 14.04.1 and 14.04.2 and 14.04.2 server.
The violet screen (with the simbols like screen and a person) appeared and after few seconds, the screen turn black and one undescore appear in the upper right corner blinking and stayed for 30 minutes. Then trying one time and another... but never appear the ubuntu main screen.

I also tryed with pendrive USB live but once the grub (only in USB, not in CD) appear and I selected "try" or "install" the screen turn to black and nothing happend (I waited like 30 minutes and nothing changed) in both cases.

I want to do dual boot with W7 but first I want to be able to start live CD at least.

Any ideas or configurations? I will appreciate so much the help.

Cheers.

Comment: The very first thing you need to do is confirm that the md5sum of your ISO matches so that you know the file was downloaded correctly: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso/503788#503788 I have Ubuntu running on numerous Gigabyte boards with no difficulty so we should start at the beginning and insure that the ISO we are trying to install is uncorrupted. To dual boot with windows 7 you are better off installing Windows 7 first and then Ubuntu as the Ubuntu boot loader (GRUB) will know how to handle it (Windows will not recognize your Ubuntu installation)

Comment: Yes, the md5 is correct. I have already installed W7 without any problem. What's next?

Comment: burn the verified ISO disk image to a disk and boot from it.

Comment: Yes, the md5 is correct. I have already installed W7 without any problem. What's next?
I have another error wich could be a clue. 
[    2.734835] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] failed to load fuc409c
[    2.734993] nouveau E[  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] failed to create 0x18000717, -22
[    2.735088] nouveau E[     DRM] failed to create 0x00000080, -22

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: Try adding `nomodeset` to the grub boot parameters - see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/183386/nouveau-driver-issue-when-trying-to-boot-ubuntu

Comment: With the verified usb-live made by startup disk creator.

After violet screen presh space, select english and "try..." then black screen and then the errors

Comment: With the nomodeset option selected and try ubuntu without installing, the same error appear

Comment: Have you tried this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/567965/nouveau-error-unknown-chipset-during-startup-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Silly solution, I removed graphic card and run with the motherboard graphic card. Now the system load like magic. Thanks for the help

Comment: You may have a defective card.. You may wish to write up your solution as answer so that others with the same issue may benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the best choice is extract the graphic card, install ubuntu and then install nvidia drivers before insert again the graphic card. It must be noveau driver which doesn't support my MSI GeForce GTX750 OC 2GB GDDR5

Answer (score 0):

friend.I have the same question.
Flow the pattern in the under , will be ok.

Access the bios,select the "periherals"Tab.
The "Inlt display first" Change to "igfx".
Change the cable of display from graphic card to motherboard.

Restart! It will be Ubuntu Time!